# Converting Flowable<List<T>> to Single<Boolean>

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, rx-kotlin

I have an function in `@Dao`. Lets call that class `DaoClass`

`abstract fun getData() : Flowable<List<Data>>`

Now, I want to check if list of data returned is empty or not. I dug through the DaoClass_Impl (generated at build time) and I found out that the Flowable won't be empty. So,

`getData().isEmpty` will always return false.

So what I did was 
`getData().singleOrError().map{it.isEmpty()}` to return if the returned list is actually empty.

But I am having problem as the value is not getting emitted.

Comment: Dao provides you with a new version of data, whenever the source of your query is updated. Are you sure you want to transform this stream of datas to Single and not to Flowable<Boolean> to check if the list is empty every time?

Comment: @MarcinJedynak  have to use Observables.zip and for that I need Single<Boolean>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to check what `singleOrError` actually does:

> Returns a Single that emits the single item emitted by this Flowable, if this Flowable emits only a single item, otherwise if this Flowable completes without emitting any items a NoSuchElementException will be signaled and if this Flowable emits more than one item, an IllegalArgumentException will be signaled.

What you're looking for is `firstOrError`, which returns just the first value emitted.